# Choice of the ridge parameter using leave-p-out estimation of the risk

Tags: statistics

The context of my question is the kernel ridge regression (in the field of Statistics). The question is to find a closed formula for $\lambda^{*}$
\begin{align*}
\lambda^{*}=\underset{\lambda >O }{\text{argmin}}~\hat{R_{p}}(\lambda)
\end{align*}
where $\hat{R_{p}}(\lambda)$ is defined by, $\forall \lambda >0$,
\begin{align}
\hat{R_{p}}(\lambda)=\frac{1}{p{n \choose p}}\sum_{e}\sum_{i\in \overline{e}}(Y_{i}-\hat{f_{\lambda}^{e}}(x_{i}))^{2}.
\end{align} 
where $n\in\mathbb{N}^{*},1\leq p \leq n$ ; $(x_{i},Y_{i})_{i\in\{ 1, \ldots, n\}}$ is the sample ; e$\subset\{ 1, \ldots, n\}$ with cardinality $n-p$ ; e and $\overline{e}$ are respectively the training sample and the test sample ($\overline{e}$ is the complementary of $e$); $K^{i,e}$ is a $1\times\text{card(e)}$ vector $(k(x_{i},x_{j}))_{j\in e}$ for $i\in\{ 1, \ldots, n\}$ fixed ; $K^{e,e}$ is a $card(e)\times card(e)$ matrix $(k(x_{i},x_{j}))_{(i,j)\in e\times e}$ ;  $\hat{f_{\lambda}^{e}}(x_{i})=K^{i,e}(K^{e,e}+\lambda I_{n-p})^{-1}Y_{e}$.

I should precise that $K^{e,e}$ is positive semi-definite symmetric matrix because the Gram matrix $K=(k(x_{i},x_{j}))_{(i,j)\in\{ 1, \ldots, n\}^{2}}$ is a positive semi-definite symmetric matrix.
My Supervisor give me the idea to use :
\begin{align*}
(I-M)^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}M^{k} \quad \text{ valid if }\quad||M||_{2}<1.
\end{align*}
Thus, we use the approximation valid if $\lambda>||K||_{2}$
\begin{align*}
(K^{e,e}+\lambda I)^{-1}&=\lambda^{-1}(I+\lambda^{-1}K^{e,e})^{-1}\\
&\approx\sum_{k=0}^{N}(-\lambda^{-1}K^{e,e})^{k}.
\end{align*}
Replacing $(K^{e,e}+\lambda I)^{-1}$ by $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{N} (-\lambda^{-1}K^{e,e})^{k}$ leads to an approximation of $\hat{R_{p}}(\lambda)$ denoted by $\hat{R_{p}^{N}}(\lambda)$. Then, instead of finding out a closed formula for $\lambda^{*}$, we hope to find a solution to for a fixed $N\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$
\begin{align*}
\lambda_{N}^{*}=\underset{\lambda >O }{\text{argmin}}~\hat{R_{p}^{N}}(\lambda)
\end{align*}
 I manage to compute a closed formula for $\hat{R_{p}^{0}}$ and $\hat{R_{p}^{1}}$ but the problem that I meet is that the approximation is valid for $\lambda > ||K||_{2}$ and not for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}_{+}^{*}$.
My question is to find out a closed formula for $\lambda^{*}$ or at least $\hat{R_{p}}$.